# Why doesnt this php statement work?

Tags: php, logical-operators

I'm trying to grab the month, and if a certain month (`11` OR `12`) `echo` something. Why does 
this work :

```
if ( date("m") == '11' )  echo 'asdf'
```

And this does not :

```
if ( date("m") == '11' ||  '12' )  echo 'asfd'
```

Comment: Check out this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php#101724

Comment: I am surprised the first one works without a `;` at the end of the echo

Comment: second one is messing it too

Answer (score 12):

The correct way is

```
if ( date("m") == '11' || date("m") == '12' ) echo 'asfd';
```

Comment: Thanks but it was hard to reach this mark, hats off to all who crossed beyond that.

Answer (score 4):

Explanation for why it doesn't work: operator precedence

`||` has a higher operator precedence than `==`, so it is evaluated first... `11 || 12` evaluates to a Boolean true; and `date('m')` gives a number between 1 and 12... any positive integer will give a true when compared (`==`) with Boolean true, so the `if` test is always valid